# Web2py auto repeat actions

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py

How can I run some function in my web2py server which will repeat for example once in 5 minute, with out any request from users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the book section on [background tasks](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#Running-tasks-in-the-background).